# Unable to modify a DIV style with css (from a SharePoint webpart, hardcoded with a DLL)

Tags: css, sharepoint, dll, web-parts

I am trying to modify a div which has the style already defined in a DLL (SharePoint webpart):

[Picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ8GM.png)

Tried several things with no luck, like

```
div[style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; MARGIN: 0em; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 100%; PADDING-RIGHT: 8px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; COLOR: #525252; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; BORDER-TOP: #d8d8d8 1px solid; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; PADDING-TOP: 3px"] {display:none;}
```

Maybe is not possible

Comment: i don't see a div with that exact styling in your code.

Comment: You are right, gonna review, maybe copy pasted too fast...

Comment: Simple as that, thanks cocoa!!